# PHPExcel: Document opens in protected view, formulas are zeroes

Tags: phpexcel

I'm generating some complex Excel file with lot of worksheets and formulas. Those formulas are referencing other worksheets. But I have two worksheet that are alike, they have same "template", just different values and formulas referencing different cells.

When file is generated and open in Excel, it's opened in protected view and some formulas in first of mentioned worksheet are not calculated and are zeroes. In second worksheet everything works fine. When I click "Edit Anyway" values get calculated and everything works fine.

I can't find reason why two almost same sheets are behaving different and why simple `=SUM()` formula can't get calculated even if file is downloaded from internet.
What can possibly cause this behavior? I won't post code since it's tens of hundreds lines long and I use wrapper class, but it's just writing values into cells.

I have tried this tricks:

```php
PHPExcel_Calculation::getInstance($objPHPExcel)->clearCalculationCache();
PHPExcel_Calculation::getInstance()->clearCalculationCache();
$objWriter->setPreCalculateFormulas(false);
```

But none of them works.

Thanks for every tip what can be cause of this.

Comment: Does this happen with any Excel file downloaded from the Internet, or only those created by PHPExcel?

Comment: If i download it from localhost then everything works fine even the first sheet is calculated. But if i download it from internet, the first sheet contains just zeroes. But second is fine again, even if it's from internet.

And I don't know what other documents does, I need to solve problem with generating this document of mine.

Comment: Obviously MS Excel considered localhost to be "safe"

Comment: Yes but this doesn't help. I need to achieve same behavior of first sheet than in second sheet in disregard of origin of file. And I can't imagine what can cause not calculating values in one sheet but calculate them in another sheet. Even if they're almost same sheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was my formulas were SUM() and first cell of sum was empty. Just next cell of sum contained value. So i've set start of SUM range to next row and everything counts just fine.

Answer (score 5):

I've just experienced the same problem. The correct solution was:

```
$objWriter->setPreCalculateFormulas(TRUE);
```

The problem is caused by PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007 and maybe other writers, that have set the preCalculateFormulas value to FALSE by default.